# Selenium WebDriver SetPageLoadTimeout does not work in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, timeout, pageload, selenium-chromedriver

I have been working on Selenium web driver in Chrome and cannot set the default page load wait time. When testing slower web pages driver times out after 60 seconds.

I have tried two approaches:

## 1:

```
TimeSpan PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);
driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverPath);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(PageLoad);
```

and

## 2:

```
public static void WaitForPageLoading()
{         
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(iwdCurrentlyUsedDriver,     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
 wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
  {
   try
   {
   string test = ((OpenQA.Selenium.IJavaScriptExecutor)EngineGloblalVariables.iwdCurrentlyUsedDriver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").ToString();
    if (test.Equals("complete"))
         return true;
    return false;
    }
    catch
    {                   
     return false;
    }
  });
   }
```

The second solution is used after the driver is navigated to page. I managed to succesfully use the second solution when working with Firefox, but Chrome still times out after 60 seconds. Is there any other way of setting or changing the default timeout for page load?

EDIT:

Exception message:

```
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
http://localhost:14545/session/4e0f1edcbc87d06360b6c89a06574476/buttonup timed out after
60 seconds.
```

Comment: "Times out", with what? Full error and stack trace please.

Comment: I edited the post and added exception message. I cannot add whole stack trace because tests are run trough an application on remote server without Visual Studio and that server is the only one slow enough to get this exception. 
Fixed "Times out" :D

Answer (score 0):

please use this.
driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), firefoxProfile, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));

- TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4) --> time out in 4 min

Comment: Hi. Tnx for your answer but I am unclear, is this using Firefox driver profile for Chrome or Firefox since Firefox is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me

```
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.None;

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
```